# Laravel 5 Redirect from a sub-method

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

I'm using Socialite to get user information from facebook. All is going well but my redirect isn't working

### Sub-routes

> I read that it's not possible to do a redirect from a submethod, or
>   any method that's not in your routes.

But how else can i redirect the user after I logged them in?

My URL looks like this after the successfull facebook handshake

```
http://tmdb.app/auth/login/facebook?code=AQBTKNZIxbfdBruAJBqZ8xx9Qnz...
```

### Code

```
class SocialController extends Controller {

    public function login(Authenticate $authenticate, Request $request)
    {
        return $authenticate->execute($request->has('code'), $this);
    }

    public function userHasLoggedIn($data)
    {
        $user = User::where('provider_id', $data->id)->first();

        if( !$user )
        {
            $user = User::create([
                'name' => $data->name,
                'email' => $data->email,
                'provider' => 'facebook',
                'provider_id' => $data->id
            ]);
        }

        // NOT WORKING!
        return redirect('test');

    }
}
```

Comment: I propose a solution. You can see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793770/laravel-5-redirect-from-another-method

Answer (score 1):

Your login function should be handling the redirect.

I'm guessing execute returns $data if the user is sucessfully logged in and false if not.

```
class SocialController extends Controller {

    public function login(Authenticate $authenticate, Request $request)
    {
        if($data = $authenticate->execute($request->has('code'), $this))
        {
            $user = User::where('provider_id', $data->id)->first();

            // maybe delegate the user creation to another class/service?
            if( !$user )
            {
                $user = User::create([
                    'name' => $data->name,
                    'email' => $data->email,
                    'provider' => 'facebook',
                    'provider_id' => $data->id
                ]);
            }

        return redirect('test');

        }

    return redirect('fail_view');

    }

}
```

Comment: Good idea to split the user creation, a UserRepository would be good for this right?

Comment: Yes, it surely would be an interesting improvement. Pass it as an implementation to an interface would be optimal, if you are building something that is going to be complex.

Comment: What I don't understand is why it's workin for Jeffrey in this laracast: ( screenshot ) http://prntscr.com/7qp5mu

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of his routes.php file?

Comment: Sure! (screenshot) http://prntscr.com/7qp6t7, thanks!, He's only touching the @login route

Comment: Thing is, you need to create a listener. Have you done that? Review the laracast from 16:20 to 18:20.

Comment: You need to return the $listener-> etc... return $listener->userHasLoggedIn($user);

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm struggling with firstOrCreate haha, will get back!

Comment: You fixed it! It was indeed the return that was missing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using PHP header function in Laravel sub method. I try it and works properly. Hope it can help you.

```
// You can using the following code
$url= url("about-laravel");
header("Location:" . $url);
exit;

// Or using the following code to redirect and keep set flash message
$result= $this->yourMethod(); // return redirect($this->route)->with('flash_message',  'I\'m Flash Message'); for TRUE or NULL for false
if( $result ){
    return $result;
}
```